# logical operation on subset of datatable in r

Tags: r, data.table, logical-operators

I have a strange problem I can not figure out:

I would like to use a logical operation on a subset of a data.table.

```
data[1:9, 1:12, with=FALSE]

   V1 V2 V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12
1:  F  2  3   4   5   F   7   8   9  10  11  12
2: 24 23 22  21  20  19  18  17  16  15  14  13
3: 25 26  F  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
4: 48 47 46  45  44  43  42  41  40  39  38  37
5: 49 50 N1  52  53  54  55  56  57 P48  59  60
6:  F 71 70  69  68   F  66  65  64  63  62  61
7: 73 74 75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84
8: 96 95 94  93  92  91  90  89  88  87  86  85
9: 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
```

This works fine in the case:

```
data[1:9,1:12, with=FALSE] == 11

     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But not if I use less than:

```
data[1:9,1:12, with=FALSE] <= 11
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I guess it might have something to do with the columns beein "chr-type", but I need this for some and it is not clear to me why `==` should work, but not `<=`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Because `"105" <= "11"` returns `TRUE`. In other words- don't do this. Fix your formats. Otherwise you''ll never know what to expect and your code will be unstable.

Comment: Form `?Comparison` : *Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see locales. The collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising. Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after z. In Welsh ng may or may not be a single sorting unit: if it is it follows g...* and etc.